# What did Uchiha Madara do to Obito with the Black Zetsu?

Tags: naruto

**Warning for this may contain spoilers**

> As I read the Naruto Episode 656 Page 14, Obito cast Rinne Tensei then suddenly the black zetsu appeared then cast another Rinne Tensei then poof Madara is revived with real body. Now, I'm lost. What happened to Obito? Do Madara switched body with Obito? or does he consumed by the Black Zetsu?
> According to the wiki, Rinne Tensei *can re-infuse new life force energy to the bodies of those who have died.* With that said, why Madara re-infused with Obito's body? and how come that Obito died (or is he dead)? What happened to the Black Zetsu? I don't know how to put this up but here's the image sequence:

[image: The pose]

[image: The catch]

[image: The twist]

[image: the trick]

[image: the prestige]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He switched life forces with Obito. That's why he said: "Let's switch". Obito is *probably* still alive because of the Kyuubi foreshadowing that the Jinchuuriki of the Ten Tails has bigger life force than other Jinchuuriki's.

Madara is revived by Black Zetsu controlling Obito using Gedo: Rinne Tensei!

Comment: and the Black Zetsu?

Comment: Has probably served his purpose and is gone now. We can see him leaving obito's body once the rinne tensei is completed. It also shows obito still breathing/panting so it's hard to say